# 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference Android

Tags: api, dictionary, google-maps-android-api-2

```
public void onSearch(View view)
{
    EditText location_tf = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFaddress);
    String location = location_tf.getText().toString();
    List<Address> addressList = null;

    if(location != null || location.equals(""))
    {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try {
             geocoder.getFromLocationName(location,1);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Address address = addressList.get(0);   //error line
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(),address.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(" Location"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }
}
```

Comment: My code is showing error at line
Address address=addressList.get(0);

Comment: The `addressList` variable is initialized to `null` and never assigned any non-null value.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more information including the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Since `addressList` is being set to `null` in the beginning and not being modified until you call `get(0)`, it will cause an error.

```
List<Address> addressList = null;
...
addressList.get(0); // you cannot call a method of a null object
```

In order to fix this, you have to fetch the addresses from somewhere - i.e. via another method call.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the variable `addressList` is guaranteed to be `null` at that point, so a NullPointerException is guaranteed on that line.

And as others have mentioned, to circumvent the error, you need to assign the variable to something other than null or omit the line entirely.

Something that others haven't pointed out yet is that--if you do assign the variable to a non-null reference--you should also check that the list is not empty. Otherwise, you will get a different kind of error when you try to `get` an element by its index. This is the general contract of the List interface's [get method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)).